# PS1 set to display Desktop

Tags: ps1

How do I set my default PS1 to `~/Desktop`?

I have tried changing it in my `~/.bashrc` but to no avail.

Can someone give out a detailed solution to be able to make changes to PS1 to the directory we would like to have upon starting the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The PS1 variable isn't what you want to change - it only affects what prompt is displayed, not what directory you're in. Adding

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

to the end of your `.bashrc` should do what you want.